# Linear regression (best fit line)

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, linear-regression

I'm using matplotlib in python to draw (best fit-line) in linear regression... the line looks so messy unless I sort the X array(input) and the Yhat array(prediction), but is it right?

If I sort the X array & the "Yhat" array separately, the data is changing... because the Yhat opposed to X before sorting will not remain the same after sorting.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load the data
X=[]
Y=[]
for line in open('data_2d2.csv'):
    x1,x2,y=line.split(',')
    X.append([float(x1),float(x2),1])
    Y.append(float(y))

#trun X and Y into numpy array
X=np.array(X)
Y=np.array(Y)

#fig=plt.figure();
#ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
#ax.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],Y)
#plt.show()

#caculate weights
w=np.linalg.solve(np.dot(X.T,X),np.dot(X.T,Y))
print(w)
Yhat=np.dot(X,w)
fig=plt.figure();

ax.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],Y)
print(Yhat)
ax.plot((sorted(X[:,0])),sorted((X[:,1])),sorted(Yhat)))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Update what you have done so far

Comment: If the line looks messy, but looks better if you sort them individually, then that suggests your data isn't linear.

Comment: It's not snsible if you sort input and prediction after the model is built

Comment: You can get the sorted index of your sorted X-array and then use that to plot the Y-array

Comment: Share some minimum data and code you wrote to get more help

Comment: thank you for replying...I'm watching a tutorial about Linear Regression..when it comes to multiple linear regression (the plotting now is 3D ) the tutor didn't draw the line...so i tried to draw it myself..but it looked so messy until i sorted the X(first input) , X2(second input) Yhat(prediction) then plotted the line

Comment: i've added the code the command i'm having trouble with is :
ax.plot((sorted(X[:,0])),sorted((X[:,1])),sorted(Yhat)))

Comment: You're sorting each dimension individually. This removes the relation between the x,y,z data of the individual points (i.e. the first entry in x doesn't correspond to the first entry in y anymore).

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem....so this is wrong at all times??

Comment: but without this command the line is so messy!

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. Often it does not make sense to connect points by lines at all (e.g. you measure weight and height of 50 people and plot those in a weight-height diagram - connecting those independent measurements carries no information). Else you are the only one knowing which order of points you'd like to see. Then you can bring the points in that order and plot via matplotlib. Matplotlib will always connect the lines in the order the points are given to it (First line segment from (x[0],y[0]) to (x[1], y[1]), second from  (x[1],y[1]) to (x[2], y[2]) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using scipy's curve_fit() to make a non-linear fit to 3D data, make a 3D scatterplot, make a 3D surface plot, make a contour plot, and yield RMSE and R-squared fit statistics. You could change the non-linear fit to a linear fit if you change the equation used here, this should help get you started with the 3D plotting for sure.

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a, alpha, beta):
    t = data[0]
    p_p = data[1]
    return a * (t**alpha) * (p_p**beta)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
    zData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # these are the same as scipy default values in this example

    # here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)

    modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters) 

    absError = modelPredictions - zData

    SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
    MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
    RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
    print('RMSE:', RMSE)
    print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```